# MVVM View vs ViewModel binding issues

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, viewmodellocator

I have am having an issue when instantiating viewModels.

I am using a ViewModelLocator for the most part since I have to inject dependencies in most cases. However there are cases when I need to pass arguments to the ViewModel. From what I understand, I need to use the ViweModel-First approach for that. Which means I need to create a DataTemplate for ViewModel that is bound to the View at runtime. Making sure to include a constructor with the arguments I want to pass in.

The issue I am having is that when I create the ViewModel and pass in my arguments, the correct constructor is called. However because the ViewModel is bound to the view, the view calls the default parameterless constructor of the viewmodel.

Here is what the XAML looks like for the UserControl I am binding the ViewModel to:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyView">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
      <viewModels:MyViewModel></viewModels:MyViewModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

The data template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}">
   <views:MyView></views:MyView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is a sample ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private MyModel _myModel;

  public MyViewModel()
  {
  }

  public MyViewModel(MyModel myModel)
  {
    _myModel = myModel;
  }
}
```

Once I create my viewModel through code using the correct constructor to pass arguments, the viewModel is created again by the view using the default parameterless constructor of the viewModel.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and shed some light on how to setup the viewmodel-first approach so that it works correctly? I am at a loss and I have been working on this all day.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the following snippet from your `UserControl` and follow my remaining instructions, I believe you will have what you want:

**Remove this**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
      <viewModels:MyViewModel></viewModels:MyViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Now, lets say that you have a `UserControl` or `Window` bound to a `ViewModel` that you want represented in your `UserControl` or `Window`.  The way you would do this is to use a `ContentControl` inside your `UserControl` or `Window` in conjunction with a `DataTemplate` specified in a `ResourceDictionary` like so:

**.XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow"
    x:Name="ThisControl">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding NavigationRegion}"/>
        <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding ContentRegion}"/>
    </DockPanel>    
</Window>
```

The `ContentControl` will implicitly lookup the `DataTemplate` (in the hierarchy of `ResourceDictionary` objects) associated with the `ViewModel` that is bound to its `Content` property.  So lets say that we set the `ContentRegion` property in the `MainWindowViewModel` to an instance of your `MyViewModel` like so:

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        private object _navigationRegion;
        private object _contentRegion;

        public object NavigationRegion
        {
            get
            {
                return _navigationRegion;
            }
            set
            {
                _navigationRegion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NavigationRegion));
            }
        }

        public object ContentRegion
        {
            get
            {
                return _contentRegion;
            }
            set
            {
                _contentRegion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContentRegion));
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ContentRegion = new MyViewModel(new MyModel());
        }
    }
}
```

And you have a `ResourceDictionary` specified like so:

**MyResourceDictionary.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
                    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Views">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
        <views:MyView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And you have merged your `ResourceDictionary` with your `Application.Resources` in your App.xaml file like so:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The Framework is going to implicitly look for a `DataTemplate` for Data Type `MyViewModel`.  The Framework will find the `DataTemplate` for `MyViewModel` in the `ResourceDictionary` we specified and see that it should be represented by the `MyView` user control.  It's at this point that the Framework will render the `MyView` user control.

And for posterity sake:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected string _title;

        protected string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code so I can help.  It's not clear what the issue is by your comment alone.

Comment: My apologise for the confusion. I can't really post from the office. It's locked down. Basically you answered my question. Therea were 2 issues. First, since the locator was used to instantiate the view models, binding the context in the view using the locator also called the viemodel again. Second issue was defining the data context in the user control that was being returned and displayed in the content control. So it was called both by the control and though code. Thanks again.